# How do I reference the output of the previous "pipe" in a Powershell pipeline?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0

I wrote this code to get some (relative) file path:

```
function Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory() {
    return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  # returns this script's directory
}

$some_file_path = Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath "foo.json"
```

This threw the error:

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
+ $some_file_path  = Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath "fo ...
+                                                     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

This indicates to me that the output of `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory` is null - but it isn't - when I write the script out like this, it's fine:

```
$this_directory = Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory
$some_file_path = Join-Path -Path $this_directory -ChildPath "foo.json"
```

So the problem is that `$_` is null.  I would expect `$_` to be reference to the previous pipe's standard output.  The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) also suggests this, but then it seems to immediately contradict itself:

> $_ contains the current object in the pipeline object. You can use this variable in commands that perform an action on every object or on selected objects in a pipeline.

In the context of my code, `$_` seems to qualify as the "current object in the pipeline object" - but I am not using this with a command that performs an action on every object or on selected objects in a pipeline.

`$$` and `$^` looked promising, but the MSDN documentation just says a few vague things here about lexical tokens.  The documentation on `$PSItem` was equally terse.

What I would actually *like* to do is create a big pipeline:

```
$some_file_path = Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {{PREVIOUS STDOUT}} -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content {{PREVIOUS STDOUT}} | Convert-FromJson {{PREVIOUS STDOUT}} | {{PREVIOUS STDOUT}}.data
```

I'd like to know where I'm going wrong both on a conceptual and a technical level.

Comment: if `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory` returns a value that is a path, then you can pipe it directly into `Join-Path` because the `-Path` parameter accepts value by pipeline --> `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -ChildPath ...`. You don't have a current input object `$_` here because you are not using a command with a script block that can process one. If you use `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Foreach-Object { }`, you will have access to `$_` within the `Foreach` script block and can create other variables to your liking.

Comment: @AdminOfThings `ForEach-Object` seems weird here because the previous function (`Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory`) only outputs one thing (a string).  I'm not clear on whether or not it's technically an "object of type string".  Also, I want to pipe the whole output of `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory` to one parameter of `Join-Path`, and I didn't see an automatic variable that seemed suitable.

Comment: Just drop `-Path $_` and it will work.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yes, but then both `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content $_` and `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content` fail to work.  I'm not sure why the standard output of the previous pipeline is automatically routed to the `-Path` parameter either (as opposed to the -ChildPath parameter, or whatever).

Comment: That is because `Get-Content` doesn't have a parameter that binds by value from pipeline. You either need to pipe into `Foreach-Object` and use `-Path $_` or create an object property named `Path` with your path as the value before piping to `Get-Content`.

Comment: Just use `(Get-Content -Path (Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -ChildPath "foo.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)).data`. I don't understand the piping requirement. It is simpler to just use more than one line.

Comment: @AdminOfThings There's no piping requirement - the question was just to advance my understanding of the language construct.  It sounds like you're saying some functions have "pipe-friendly" parameters.  `Join-Path` has `-Path`, `Get-Content` does not have one.  How do you generally ascertain which functions have "pipe-friendly" parameters across the Powershell ecosystem?  Currently from my point of view it just looks like trial-and-error.

Comment: You can only use `$_` inside a scriptblock `{ }`.  That's pretty fundamental.  It's in the docs which parameters can be piped, some only need by value, some need by property name.

Comment: @js2010 Well... not exactly.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path.  No distinction is made at the level of the *parameters* portion of those docs.  Do you have to drill into the usage examples every time to figure out which params can be piped?

Comment: Search for "accept pipeline input" in those docs.

Comment: @js2010 Wow - *yikes*.  Alright, guess that answers my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by executing the command below:

```
(Get-Content -Path (Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -ChildPath "foo.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)).data
```

---

Some commands support pipeline parameter binding. The options are pipeline by value or pipeline by property. A good reference for parameter binding is [About Functions Advanced Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7).

Searching online for the command you are going to use will yield parameter binding information. For example [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7), has a parameters section. Each parameter will have a description including the field `Accept pipeline input:`. For a parameter to accept pipeline input, this must be `True`. Usually, it will say how the value can be passed into the pipeline (`ByPropertyName` or `ByValue`).

`ByPropertyName` indicates that you must output an object that contains a property name that matches the parameter name. Then once the object is piped, the parameter will bind to the matching property name's value. See below for an example:

```
$filePath = [pscustomobject]@{Path = 'c:\temp\test1\t.txt'}
$filePath

Path
----
c:\temp\test1\t.txt

$filePath.Path # This binds to -Path in Get-Content
c:\temp\test1\t.txt
$filepath | Get-Content
```

`ByValue` indicates that any value piped in will attempt to bind to that parameter. If there are type discrepancies at the binding time, an error will likely be thrown. See below for example:

```
"c:\temp" | Join-Path -ChildPath "filepath" # c:\temp binds to `-Path`
c:\temp\filepath
```

---

Regarding `$_`, which is synonymous with `$PSItem`, is the current input object in a script block. You typically see this used with `Foreach-Object` and `Where-Object`. If you don't have a script block, you won't be able to use `$_`.

You can technically pipe anything into `Foreach-Object` or `Where-Object`. Then the current pipeline object will be represented by `$_`. You don't need a collection as a single item can be piped in. See below:

```
"c:\temp" | Foreach-Object { $_ }
c:\temp

$filePath | Foreach-Object { $_ }

Path
----
c:\temp\test1\t.txt

$filePath | Foreach-Object { $_.Path }
c:\temp\test1\t.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example.  Search for "accept pipeline input" in the docs.  Using a scriptblock with get-content's -path parameter is a little advanced.  Most people use a foreach-object instead.  It works because -path accepts pipeline input, but only by property name.  join-path's -path paramaeter can be over the pipe by value, so it's easier.  This will come in handy a lot once you understand it.  Maybe it's easier just to try things sometimes.

```
echo '"hi"' > foo.json

'.\' | Join-Path -ChildPath foo.json | Get-Content -Path { $_ } | ConvertFrom-Json

hi
```

Or with foreach, which is short for foreach-object in this case.  But $_ must always be inside the curly braces.

```
'.\' | Join-Path -ChildPath foo.json | foreach { Get-Content $_ } | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a code block.

```
function Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory() {
    return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  # returns this script's directory
}

$some_file_path = Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json"
$some_file_path 

read-host
```

The reason it doesn't work in this code @ get-content is because it's evaluating to false there.

```
Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content {$_} and Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content $_
```

An object can only be passed on using $_ or $psItem if it evaluates to $True.

Here is why it works in the first example.

```
function Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory() {
    return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  # returns this script's directory
}

if(Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory -eq $True){
    write-host This is true
}

Output: This is true
```

You can use Parethesis to isolate your objects in the pipeline also.

example:

```
Get-Content (Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json")
```

"|" deals with the object to the left of it, so doing get-content | get-content | doesn't make sense to the script. You will need to separate it into multiple commands with a semi-colon if you're doing something like that. Or use a "Foreach" cmdlet.

`gc (Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json");gc (Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "bar.json")`

Comment: Sure, but this does not help advance my understanding of why `$_` works but only in a script-block context.  Also, the script block approach fails with both `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content {$_}` and `Get-ExecutingScriptDirectory | Join-Path -Path {$_} -ChildPath "foo.json" | Get-Content $_`.